# Сортировка данных из файла

Tags: delphi

В общем, суть вопроса:

Задан текстовый файл, содержащий фрагмент программы на Object Pascal. Найти все статические методы и поместить их в файл, состоящий из записей следующей структуры: имя метода - атрибут доступа (public, protected или private) - класс. Файл должен быть отсортирован по именам методов.

Вопрос только - как это реализовать? Искал в интернете - нет подобных программ.

**Правка:** как именно отсортировать (задавать изначальные имена всех методов, которые есть, или как то более лаконично это можно сделать?

**Правка 2:** Я так понимаю, поиск мне нужно сделать что то по типу этого:

```
 procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
 var
 i:integer;
 begin
  for  i:= 0 to memo1.lines.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if (pos('procedure',memo1.lines[i]))<> 0
    then
    begin
      memo2.Lines.insert(0,memo1.lines[i]);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @tkoff, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам наверное надо найти в файле все аля "class procedure a;" и выкинуть их в результирующий файл.

```
TMyClass = class
  public
    class procedure a;
  end;
```

Вопрос - как организовать поиск? Вариантов масса. 
можно тупо искать подстроку сlass procedure потом выдирать имя. При этом при проходе по файлу отлавливать флаг - встретили public значит в паблик зоне ну и т.д. И соответсвенно года встречаем class procedure то знаем в какой зоне - public, private  или protected.
можно написать семантический разбор.
много что можно.

Псевдо код? на поиск? Ну можно примерно так:

```
OpenFile();
currentArea = "";
while( line = ReadLine() )
{
    if(line.Contains("public "))
       currentArea = "public";
    else if(line.Contains("protected "))
       currentArea = "protected";
    else if(line.Contains("private "))
       currentArea = "private";

    if(line.Contains("class procedure "))
    {
       funcName = GetFuncNameFrom(line);
       ResultList.Add({funcName, currentArea});
    }

}
ResultList.Sort();
ResultList.SaveToFile();
```

GetFuncNameFrom - выдирает имя между procedure и ";"
Ну как то так примерно общая логика. Ещё надо добавить обработки ситуаций когда у нас
что то типа

```
...
public
class
procedure
a;
```

Но вообще правельнее сделать что нить типа редера файла по словам, и анализа потока на встречаемые слова т.е. что то типа:

```
OpenFile();
currentArea = "";
while( word = ReadWord() )
{
    if(word == "public")
       currentArea = "public";
    else if(word == "protected")
       currentArea = "protected";
    else if(word == "private")
       currentArea = "private";

    if(Previous(word)=="procedure" && Previous(Previous(word))=="class")
    {
       funcName = word;
       ResultList.Add({funcName, currentArea});
    }

}
ResultList.Sort();
ResultList.SaveToFile();
```

Функция Previous - возвращает предыдущее от аргумента слово.

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, а где можно почитать про статические методы?

Comment: Насколько мне известно, статических методов в Delphi нет, как таковых в C++, например. Статический метод - это не виртуальный( или не динамический) метод, вообщем полная противоположность виртуальности. Статические методы в Delphi - это методы, способные без ограничений перекрывать старые имена классов и при этом изменять тип методов.

Comment: Чад, можно поподробнее с поиском? (хоть бы псевдокод для того чтобы выдирать нужные нам методы с определенным атрибутом доступа)